# How to have the DataGridView do the following

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I need it to:

1. Expand the columns to fill the entire width regardless of length of strings.
2. Select the entire row on click anywhere on it.

I also need to capture a double click and retrive the value of a column, on the row a user clicked. Does the EventArgs e, have this property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking to do is set the Column Fill Mode for the width.

[Column Fill Mode in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171605.aspx)

You can handle the double click event using CellMouseDoubleClick

[DataGridView.CellMouseDoubleClick Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellmousedoubleclick.aspx)

```
DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e
row = e.RowIndex
column = e.ColumnIndex
```

Comment: Greg's answer has more detail for the row / double click

Answer (score 1):

- Expand the columns to fill the entire
  width regardless of length of
  strings:

  You'll need to modify the AutoSizeMode, MinimumWidth, FillWeight, and Resizable properties as described in the MSDN article [Column Fill Mode in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171605.aspx)
- Select the entire row on click
  anywhere on it:

  For any click event `dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected = true;`
- I also need to capture a double click
  and retrive the value of a column, on
  the row a user clicked:

  You can use the `CellContentDoubleClick` or `CellMouseDoubleClick` to access `e.ColumnIndex`

Comment: To select the entire row, better to set `SelectionMode` to `DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect`. Plus I'd avoid `CellContentDoubleClick` as you can't double click on an empty cell!